# How to create a landing page with OpenCart, using OpenCart only?

Tags: opencart

What if one would want to create a landing page/home page for opencart?

How does someone will supposed to do that?

A landing page or home page, using only opencart and no other means.

--

Clarification.

What I meant of Home Page is it's literal meaning in the context of Front-End WebDev. What I meant to say is, the page where user is redirected when they access my site's root domain.

I want to design and create a custom landing and home page. That landing page has no product content.

It shall only contain the folowing;

1. Main Navigation Menu with, Home, Online Shop, Blog links.
2. Site Name, Site Logo
3. Site Name with Tagline.
4. Banner Rotator with CTA button.
5. Footer, Footer Links to Privacy Policy, About Us and other common footer links.
6. This Home Page/Landing Page/Index Page, is a different page from the main store section. On this page, It has a home page link and a store page link. So on the main nav of this page, you shall see a Home link and a Store link. Clicking store link, shall take you to the main store section and the main nav shall show the categories, the store has.

Comment: What do You mean by *landing page for OpenCart*...? I am pretty sure OpenCart does have it's **homepage**... So, please, explain a little bit more what would You like to achieve...

Comment: I've tried adding some additional info, that might help you answering the inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what You are requesting:

> It shall only contain the folowing:
>    1. Main Navigation Menu with, Home, Online Shop, Blog links.
>    2. Site Name, Site Logo
>    3. Site Name with Tagline.
>    4. Banner Rotator with CTA button.
>    5. Footer, Footer Links to Privacy Policy, About Us and other common footer links.

**You would have to disable any module that is displaying on homepage** (*categories*, *featured*, *bestsellers*, *latest*, *specials*, etc.) **and enable only the carousel module** (or install one of Your desire) and place it on the `Content Top` position.

In that case You would have these elements:

- header (with site name, logo, main navigation)
- Your desired carousel/banner rotator
- footer (with additional links)

Is that what You are requesting?

---

**Edit 1:** I think the homepage You request is kinda nonsense... Why on earth You would like to have a *homepage with a link to* ***homepage*** *and store*? I would understand to have *a website (presentation) with a blog and store that both run within u subdirectory*, thus having a site `www.site.com`, with a blog at `www.site.com/blog/` and a store at `www.site.com/store/`. In that case I would understand that within the main site (`www.site.com`) You would have a homepage with link to `/blog/` and to `/store/`.

**BUT** if You are running **only a store** at Your domain (`www.site.com`) then having additional homepage is nonsense, as You could create a homepage described above (*header* + *text and carousel as content* + *footer*)...

---

**Edit 2:**

> Yes, that's my main idea mydomain.com would be my landing page/index page/home page. mytdomain.com/store, is the store section and also with the blog section at mydomain.com/blog.

In that case You could create just a simple static HTML page that will contain static text and a javascript carousel (banner rotator/slider). After You have installed the blog and store to their subdirectories then just create a link to both of them within Your static homepage that lays in the root of the web folder and is called `index.html`.

Another way how to achieve this with slightly more effort is to have the desired blogging system installed in the root, editing it's homepage while having the main blog on a subpage and a store within a subdirectory. Many people run wordpress/drupal installation at `www.site.com` and an OpenCart installation at `www.site.com/store/`. Within a wordpress site You can then have a subpage `/blog/` where You will post all of Your blog posts...

So is this the final solution?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why someone would want to do that is for marketing purposes. Creating unique content is extremely important for SEO. The opencart default page does not have much area for landing pages or gateway pages. You may have to improvise to achieve this.

What I would recommend is just create your landing page and then use .htaccess file in /public_html folder to use whatever page you created, inside the landing page code use href links that take you to the products. This would be your best bet.